# How To Join Two Tables Having Some Values Same in the Column

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, join

Every One
It's Related To MYSQL Query...
I have Two Tables ...
Table A is like

```
|ID | Field 1| Field 2 |
------------------------
| 01 | ASD    | SDF     |
------------------------
| 02 | ghg    | OOi     |
------------------------
```

B is Like

```
------------------------
|ID | Field A | Field B |
-------------------------
| 1 | XYZ     | AB01    |
| 2 | XYZ     | AB02    |
-------------------------
```

Now in Field B In Table B Value - AB01 
here  01 is the Value of ID Of Table A .

Now My Question is that How to use inner Join in Both A AND B Table

Like 
From B
inner Join TableA On ??? [What will be in On Clause ...??]

Comment: Is there any One ...????

Comment: there is no relation between them technically, Field A of table B is not equal to field 1 of Table A.

Comment: Solution is that, you need to create a column in Table B for reference of Table A id...

Comment: Boss ..!! I think There will be Some other Solution.. Because One Part Is Constant and another is variable and same as ID Field Of Table A...

Comment: yes i checked u need to 01 from AB01 use substring

Comment: Thanks... All for .. Suggestions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use SUBSTRING function like:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.id = SUBSTRING(b.FieldB, 3, 2)
```

This will return you all records.

SUBSTRING in mysql have three params.

- your field name (your field name)
- starting point (where you want to start)
- length (how many character do you want)

Like:

```
SUBSTRING( string, start_position, [ length ] )
```

or

```
SUBSTRING( string FROM start_position [ FOR length ] )
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ID is a string between `01` and `99`:

```
select  *
from    TableA a
join    TableB b
on      a.id = substring(b.FieldB, 3, 2)
```

Comment: Please Explain This -- a.id = substring(b.FieldB, 3, 2) why 3,2 are written

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this
DECLARE @RESULT TABLE
(        
        ID      INT, 
        Field_1 varchar(10),
        Field_2 varchar(10)

)        
INSERT @RESULT VALUES
(01, 'ASD','SDF')
,(02, 'ghg','OOi')

DECLARE @RESULT1 TABLE
(        
        ID      INT, 
        Field_a varchar(10),
        Field_b varchar(10)

)        
INSERT @RESULT1 VALUES
(01, 'xyz','ab01')
,(02, 'xyz','ab02')

select * from  @RESULT r1 inner join @RESULT1 r2
on right(r2.Field_b,2)=r1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

// Like this

```
SELECT * FROM TableNAme INNER JOIN SecondTableName ON TableName.ID=SecondTableName.ID;
```